# Post-commit hook gives Segmentation fault when try to exec svn update

Tags: svn, segmentation-fault, fault

Executing svn update from post-commit hook  or from a php page [exec('svn up /var/www/test)]. Something goes wrong and returns segmentation fault error.

The same happen if I try to exec `svn commit` from a php page (with or without user and password).

Repositories in `var/svn` (www-data owner) 644 permission.
Working copy in `var/www/` (www-data owner) 644.

I tried with chmod 777 on `var/www/test` but same error occurred.

Someone can tell me why this error occur?

- Ubuntu 11.10 server on virtual machine (host Windows 7 64)
- SVN 1.7.6
- php  5.3.6-13 ubuntu3.8
- Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
- Svnserve running with www-data privileges

Comment: What is the exact error? What gets logged on server? What is the hook script code?

Comment: exact error is "segmentsation fault" nothing else

Comment: the svn command been executed but for some reason abort, in fact after that, svn need a cleanup command to exec other command even from command line or other client.

Comment: the code is a simple `svn up wokingcopypath`. --- syslog: `ubuntu kernel :[2244.700308] svn[2332]: segfault at c4$p 00b4546e sp bf96e8c8 error 4 in ld-2.13.so[b3a000+1e000]`--- apache2 error.log: no error –